# Mercurial on IIS 8.5 and Windows 2012 R2 with network shares

Tags: iis, version-control, mercurial

I'm setting up Mercurial 3.6.2 on IIS 8.5 and Windows Server 2012 R2. Everything works as expected, except for the fact that we can't serve repositories located on network drives. The network repos have read/write permissions and are shared for everyone on the filesystem.

The [paths] section of our hgweb.config looks like:

```
[paths]
Repo1 = c:\hg\repo_xxx
Repo2 = d:\hg\repo_xxx
Network_repo = \\ServerName\hg\repo_xxx
```

The first two repos are served by IIS without any problem, the network repo on the other hand gives an '*error accessing repository*' exception. In our production environment, we cannot host the repos on the same machine as the webserver.

Any ideas on how to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a solution for it. IIS had security problems serving the network repos with pass-through authentication. A workaround for this was using the credentials of a specific user with appropriate rights on website level. (NOT ApplicationPool level!)

So in IIS manager:

1. Select your website, click basic settings in the right-hand panel.
2. Click on the 'Connect as...' button.
3. Choose specific user, click Set.
4. Provide a user (domain\username) and password with enough privileges.